# Import from node_modules without ../

Tags: javascript, emacs

When I auto import a file from node modules I want it to be like

```
import ComponentX from "@package/folder"
```

Instead I get something like

```
import ComponentX from "../../../node_modules/@package/folder/index"
```

My `jsconfig.json` looks like this

```
{
  "compileroptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "baseurl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I use emacs with lsp and ts-server.

Comment: Is this question relevant to Emacs somehow?

Comment: @phils since I tried all basic jsconfigs I found on the internet and they don't work the same for emacs I'd say so. I assume there should be an emacs specific hack to get my desired result.

Comment: So the things you've found on the internet *are* working when you edit the code with other editors, and are only not working when you edit the code with Emacs?

Comment: @phils yes, some editors don't even require the jsconfig file to figure out imports, and work fine with configs like the one in the post (not that i'm complaining about emacs)

Comment: Ok.  I don't understand the question at all in that case (it sounded like it was a code problem of some kind).  Hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is gonna give you some insight,

"baseurl" : "src" mean the base path starting point is in the dir /scr,

so try change the base path to the root of your app,

change your baseurl to -> "baseurl" : "."

Comment: and for @directory , add some line below baseurl 
"paths" : {
"@/<dirname>" : "<dirname>/*"
}
change the <dirname> with your directory that you want